# Nine-patch image shows strange behaviour?

Tags: android, android-layout, nine-patch

I am creating an app in Android which implements Chat feature in it. I have 2 kind of chat bubbles - blue for other user and orange for logged in user. I am using Nine-patch images for these bubbles because the bubble can be stretched.

The text in the blue bubble is showing fine - right in the center(as shown in the figure below). But the text in the orange bubble is showing after some vertical gap from the upper border of the image. I can't figure out why this is happening.  Both the bubbles have same properties and have been created following the same procedure. Please help. Thanks in advance.

[image: chatbubbles]

Here is the orange chat bubble:

[image: orangebubble]

Comment: It would be helpful if you added the nine-patch image itself to the post, otherwise there's very little to go on

Comment: Please post your orange ninepatch image.

Comment: ok. I am uploading that.

Comment: @ kcoppock, @ kingraam : I have uploaded the orange chat bubble. Please see if you find anything wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in the nine-patch.. the right hand border defines where the content goes and you have it starting just under the pointy part of the speech bubble. Continue the border up to where you want the content to start and it will work!

To clarify: the right and bottom borders define where the content can go, and the top and left borders define the area of the image that will be repeated when the image needs to be stretched.

Try this:
[image]

Comment: Also, you're stretching the pointing portion of the bubble by having a line on the left! You only need one pixel on the top and left sides -- cross-sections that *don't* intersect with the arrow.

Comment: @ kcoppock : I don't understand what are you trying to say.

Comment: I've edited my answer to include an amended image. Hopefully this will make it clear. The top and left borders only need to be 1 pixel in this case as they are defining the pixel that should be stretched when the image needs to get bigger. The line you had before on the left included the pointy part so that was being stretched

Comment: @PadmaKumar Yes it will, but it depends on what your end goal is. If the arrow should stay centered, he should put another dot. If the arrow should stay at the top, it is fine as it is.

Comment: Yep - I assumed the distance from the top to the top of the arrow should remain fixed

Answer (score 0):

draw9 will stretch as what you want.

//your image width is too long. use this one for your reference. 
//this image will work fine for me as I am using for left side.

your orange chat bubble is also fine if you put one dot on the right side above the arrow.

[image]